# Making Syslog server Web-based

Tags: syslog

How can you make your syslog server become web-based so that you can check syslog from 
anywhere with secure manner? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a Myriad of web front ends available for syslog. [LogZilla](http://www.logzilla.net) is my favorite. It's extremely fast and very easy to use. There's also Splunk, but it is insanely expensive, or graylog2, but it doesn't scale well. Or loggly, but it is slow and cloud-only.